# Impenetrable confusing definition of API

Tags: api, specifications, definition

So I was going through the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) on API, in the first paragraph it is stated that

> A document or standard that describes how to build or use such a connection or interface is called an API specification. A computer system that meets this standard is said to implement or expose an API. The term API may refer either to the specification or to the implementation.

While I understand the 'specification' part of the definition, I didn't get what 'implementation' here means.

Taking Python as an example, whenever I'm writing a program in it I understand that I'm using it's API specification (or API), but what does 'implementation' mean here? Is it the source code of the Python that was used to build this API or object code or something else. And if it really is source code or object code, then it feels counter-intuitive to call them as API to me — so far in my experience I used to see only specification as API. So, if you could kindly help me to resolve this long lasting query, I'll be highly grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Let's say we have a module A.py, and we imported it in B.py, I understand that all the available classes, functions & variables from A.py form the API specification (or API), but what about the 'implementation' part here? Do we call entire A.py as the API as well?

Comment: To "Is it specifically Java where we call implementation as API as well?": Nobody would call the implementation an API, not even in Java.
APIs are about Interfaces. One thing talks to another. If the Java backend is Oracle Java (an implementation) or GraalVM (an implementation) does not change the Interface you use.

To wikipedia: Everybody can change an article. Change it to be more understandable / less misleading and the wikipedians will accept or reject the change. Piece of cake.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, people use the term 'API' to refer to a library that implements a particular API. This strikes me as a mis-use of the term, but it might be what motivated the Wikipedia article to say "The term API may refer ... to the implementation". There's some discussion of that on [the article's 'Talk' page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:API#Little_bit_of_confusion...).

Comment: Thanks, I was dying to hear other's opinion on this, but people were like we only care about code & money, not definitions & theory.

Comment: From the 'talk page' it appears that this second meaning is for Java only. I wish Wikipedia was perfect, at least for STEM.

Answer (score 0):

"The term API may refer ... to the implementation" is just a suboptimal wording.
Just take the later in that wikipedia article "The calls that make up the API are also known as subroutines, methods, requests, or endpoints. An API specification defines these calls, meaning that it explains how to use or implement them." which points to what I would phrase "the way you call functions, methods, etc. in a programming language are part of the 'API' of that programming language".
The thing that I stipulate the author of "... to the implementation" meant. You could contact him/her directly to clarify that.

It is complicated because API, protocol, ABI have quite some overlap. "API" is in practice the catch-all for saying "something interacts in a controlled way with a system. May it be an Interpreter, an HTTP-service, a dynamic library (because it is ... "an interface (of some kind) to a system" (of some kind).

That said: "implementation" is IMHO a misleading wording. The API is the interface.
If I do a GET request to nginx or apache ... the "API" would be HTTP and the implementation however nginx and apache do to reply to the HTTP request.
If I do a function call to a Python function the API is the function signature; if the backend (what I would call the "implementation" is CPython or PyPy is not the API but the implementation.

The pointers to the talk page for that wikipedia article are worth a lot!

Answer (score 0):

### API and implementations with analogy

I like to think of APIs and implementations with a help of an analogy with some real-world devices, like a car for example. Each car has a steering system, which helps you steer the car (obviously). But in order to use this system, you don't have to know how it works and how it's implemented, so you *interface* with it via a steering wheel. This also has the benefit of each car manufacturing company having a relative freedom of how they can implement the steering system (because at the end of the day all the driver is worried about is the steering wheel). So in this example the steering wheel would be your API/interface, the steering system is the implementation and the driver is some client application.

### APIs and implementations in code

This works similarly in code. When developing a software system or a library, you always choose which components (classes/methods/variables) are exposed to the client applications (the ones which use your system/library), and which ones stay hidden from them and become an implementation detail. The first is the API while the latter is the implementation. Imagine you develop a library of collection classes and utilities, and as part of your API you expose a `sort(collection)` function, which, as the name states, sorts a collection. Client applications will call this *API* without caring how it's *implemented*, so later you can change the underlying sorting algorithm without breaking any clients (they probably won't even know something changed, they are just calling the function same as before). In other words, your *implementation* can change without any changes to the *API*.

### API specifications

Now, where the wording can get confusing is when we add API specifications into the mix. API specifications are often human-readable documents which describe said API (what classes/methods should be there and how they should behave). Such specifications are not code, they are just text-based documents aimed to guide developers to provide an implementation for this API. When a library implements such API specification, it will contain the actual *API* (code components which correspond to the specification and are exposed to the clients) and *implementation* (code components hidden from clients which do the actual work and are called by the API). Now, where confusion lies is that the whole library (including both API and implementation) can be called an implementation of the API specification (because this is actual code implementing what is written in a text document, even though this code contains both API and implementation). I think this is what is meant in the Wiki:

> The term API may refer either to the specification or to the implementation.

meaning that when you hear the term `API` it can refer to either a formal text-based document describing said API or to the actual code components which form the API of some software implementation.

*Word on Java interfaces: Java interfaces are basically code components which **only** have an API, meaning they have no implementation and are meant to be implemented by other classes. This allows developers to have API specifications in code so to speak, where they provide a package which contains only interfaces, and other vendors can use those when developing their implementations. This lets you enforce the specification more reliably, because now instead of simply relying on a document, implementation developers will add those interfaces as code dependencies and rely on the compiler to check whether they implemented every method correctly (of course they still need to worry about the intended behaviour themselves). That said, this only adds to the confusion, because now actual code can also be called an API specification.*